# Android Fragment Callback Interface throws null

Tags: android, interface, nullpointerexception, callback, fragment

Hi I have a fragment callback interface method that works well on Android 7.1.0 but it throws this null exception in Android 5.0.0. How do I fix this? I appreciate the help.

[image]

Codes

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.radio0:
                    answer = radio0.getText().toString();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio1:
                    answer = radio1.getText().toString();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2:
                    answer = radio2.getText().toString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

@OnClick(R.id.button_submit)
public void submitAnswer()
{

    if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1)
    {
        datapass(true, answer.toString());
    }
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}



public void datapass(Boolean hasAnswer, String answer)
{
   fragmentCallBackInterface.passAnswer(hasAnswer, answer);
}
```

FragmentCallBackInterface

```
public interface FragmentCallBackInterface 
{
    public void passAnswer(boolean answerBool, String answerString);
}
```

The activity where the interface is implemented

```
public class QuizActivity extends BaseActivity implements 
FragmentCallBackInterface 
{
    boolean answerBool;
    String answerString;

    @Override
    public void passAnswer(boolean answerBool, String answerString)
    {
        this.answerBool = answerBool;
        this.answerString = answerString;

    }
}
```

Comment: without additional code it is difficult to help you

Comment: Well... Where did you assign the interface?

Comment: Any small advice would be a great help. Like what I have said, this is working on Android 7.1.0 but it throws null exception on Android 5.0.0.

Comment: could you paste the logcat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has member variable fragmentCallBackInterface been initialized, and where?
You can initialize it in onAttach.

NOTICE that before android 6.0 or API 23 it's onAttach(Activity). However afterwards it was changed to onAttach(Context).

You should still use the onAttach(Activity) or it of course can't run on Android 5.

Comment: Changed onAttach(Context) to onAttach(Activity). Now it works. Thanks.